# Lector RFID conectado a Puerto USB

Tags: windows-forms

Tengo un proyecto pero es en **Windows Form** y soy principiante en ese ambiente. tengo el siguiente código para tratar de leer datos de un lector RFID de tarjetas de proximidad y mostrar el ID de dicha tarjeta en un `textbox`, el lector se conecta por USB, quisiera saber si alguien me puede echar una mano.

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private SerialPort RFID;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
            RFID = serialPort;
            RFID.PortName = "COM1";
            RFID.BaudRate = 9600;
            RFID.DataBits = 8;
            RFID.Parity = Parity.None;
            RFID.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            RFID.Open();
            RFID.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(RFID_DataReceived);
            prueba();
        }


        private void prueba()
        {
            textBox2.Text = "test";
        }

        private void RFID_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Inica Componentes");
            string data = RFID.ReadExisting();
            textBox2 .Text = "77777";
        }

       }
    }
```

Comment: Que tipo de lector utilizas? tengo algo de experiencia con RFID HID Omnikey 5427 CK

Comment: Hola, es un lector PCprox, el modelo es RDR-6082AKU se conecta por USB

Comment: En mi experiencia con el Omnikey no necesariamente tiene que ser serial la coneccion, yo lo utilizo con puerto USB y al pasar la tarjeta por el lector este me arroja caracteres hexadecimales que luego hay que convertir para poder obtener el ID real de la tarjeta, estoy mirando el manual y es muy distinto https://www.rfideas.com/files/kn_center_resource/attachments/RFIDeas-pcProx_Plus_Enroll_Wiegand-Manual.pdf no creo poder ayudarte mucho pero te dejo el manual del mismo. Suerte!

Comment: Es que mi lector esta por USB, si leí esos manuales y francamente no me sirvieron de mucho, soy nuevo en esto y no se si este correcto el codigo que añadí, mi lector esta por USB pero los ejemplos que encuentro solo manejan puerto serial.

Comment: Hola Amigo Manny como puedo comunicarme contigo. necesito realizar un proyecto utilizando un lector de tarjeta de proximidad. quisiera saber si el lector RFID HID Omnikey 5427 CK es la adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mira esta porcion de codigo, yo lo utilice para conectarme y obtener datos de una bascula mediante el puerto serial, espero te ayude a guiarte por el lado correcto.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;  

private delegate void DelegadoAccesso(string accion);
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Enabled == true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            string data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            this.BeginInvoke(new DelegadoAccesso(si_DataReceived), new object[] { data });
        }

    }

    private void si_DataReceived(string accion)
    {
        //string pesoActual = accion.Substring(2, 6).Trim();
        if (accion.Contains("GS") && accion.Contains("+"))
        {
            label3.Text = accion;
            label3.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if(accion.Contains("-") || accion.Contains("GS"))
        {
            label3.BackColor = Color.Red;
            label3.Text = accion;
            //label3.Text = "0";
        }
        else if (accion.Contains("G"))
        {
            label3.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
         //accion.Trim();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
            serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 500;
            serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 500;
            serialPort1.Open();
            label2.Text = "Conectado";
            serialPort1.Write("0P");//aqui yo le estoy pidiendo datos constantemente, lo puede borrar
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: El dispostivo de medición no esta conectado\n" + ex.Message,"Bascula Error");
        }
    }
```

Dale una revisada y adaptalo a tus necesidades, este codigo a mi me funciona.
Suerte.

Comment: De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda, soy muy nuevo con RFID y mu duda es que si mi lector se conecta por USB seria el mismo código o tendría que buscar la manera de leer desde USB?